# Jhipster, Unable to connect containerized mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose, jhipster

I'm trying to use docker to run my jhipster microservices.

I had no problem when running without Docker. But now i'm facing some problem when tryin to run my microservice using docker.

everytime i execute

> docker-compose -f app.yml up

command on my UAA server, it shows this error when running the UAA server.

```
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:38:59.725 DEBUG 6 --- [           main] i.c.f.uaa.config.CacheConfiguration      : No cache
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:06.897 DEBUG 6 --- [           main] i.c.f.u.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration    : Starting Swagger
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:06.914 DEBUG 6 --- [           main] i.c.f.u.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration    : Started Swagger in 16 ms
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:07.004 DEBUG 6 --- [           main] i.c.f.uaa.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : Configuring Mongobee
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:07.020  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.github.mongobee.Mongobee             : Mongobee has started the data migration sequence..
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:37.056  WARN 6 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource [id/co/fifgroup/uaa/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:37.074  INFO 6 --- [           main] i.c.f.uaa.config.CacheConfiguration      : Closing Cache Manager
uaa-app_1            | 2017-04-17 07:39:37.129 ERROR 6 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
uaa-app_1            |
uaa-app_1            | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource [id/co/fifgroup/uaa/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

and this is my UAA server app.yml inside of docker directory.

```
version: '2'
services:
uaa-app:
    image: uaa
    external_links:
        - uaa-mongodb:mongodb
        - jhipster-registry:registry
    environment:
        - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,swagger
        - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:admin@registry:8761/config
        - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017
        - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=uaa
        - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=15 # gives time for the database to boot before the application 
uaa-mongodb:
    extends:
        file: mongodb.yml
        service: uaa-mongodb
jhipster-registry:
    extends:
        file: jhipster-registry.yml
        service: jhipster-registry
    environment:
        - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/docker-config/
```

uaa-mongodb and jhipster-registry works fine with docker, but my UAA server unable to connect to uaa-mongodb.

and why the error keep saying that i using localhost:27017 even thoug i tried to change **SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI** and **spring.data.mongodb.uri** inside application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml into difference value.

can someone help me with this problem...

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question, this all i did with my script.

i change app.yml file into

```
version: '2'
services:
    uaa:
        image: uaa:latest
        external_links:
            - uaa-mongodb:mongodb
            - jhipster-registry:registry
        links : 
            - uaa-mongodb:mongodb
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger,test
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:admin@registry:8761/config
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:admin@registry:8761/config 
            - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongodb
            - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
            - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=uaa
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=15 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
    jhipster-registry:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-registry.yml
            service: jhipster-registry
        environment:
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/docker-config/
    uaa-mongodb:
        extends:
            file: mongodb.yml
            service: uaa-mongodb
```

and my application-pro.yml into

```
eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        enabled: true
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE}

spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST}
            port: ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT}
            database: ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE}
```

now my UAA server successfully connect to containerized mongodb database.
but now i'm having new error..

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:815)
uaa_1                |  at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104)
uaa_1                |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
uaa_1                |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
uaa_1                |  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
uaa_1                |  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
uaa_1                |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
uaa_1                |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
uaa_1                |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```